# Android production app, rare out-of-bounds-exception crash

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, production

Android app rare production out-of-bounds exception.

My production app sometimes has a rare out-of-bounds-exception crash, which has only ever occurred on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2016), 2048 MB RAM, Android 8.1.   I cannot properly diagnose which index is OOB.  Also I cannot see how any of the indexes can possible be wrong anyway.  Am I missing something obvious, can anyone help please?

The app has prod versions 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 & 1.3.

There are crash reports of this happening in v 1.0 on March 30th, and again this week in v 1.2 on May 11th,

Although I could not diagnose it, I attempted some fixes for the 1.0 March 30th crash.  These ‘fixes’ are live in version 1.2.   So, moving on, 1.2 had a similar crash this week on May 11th (actually 5 crashes over several hours, all on the same device).

The code is:

```
    public Bitmap[][] balloonBitmap = new Bitmap[6][6];

    public int[] dynamicObjectRId = new int[10];


for (int j = 1; j <= totalNoOfDynamicImages; j++) {


    // PROD CRASH March 30th: OOB was on the next line 
    **balloonBitmap[correctOptionColourNo][j] = ImageUtil.loadImage(res, db.dynamicObjectRId[j], 
    dynamicImageWidthQT3, dynamicImageHeightQT3)**;

    // PROD CRASH May 11th seems to be on this line:
    *byteCountforBitmaps += balloonBitmap[correctOptionColourNo][j].getByteCount();*

    }
```

The fix I tried is done earlier in the method: (live in v1.2)

```
if  ((correctOptionColourNo < 0) || (correctOptionColourNo > 5)) {
    correctOptionColourNo = 3;
}

So correctOptionColourNo should be ok, not OOB.
```

The OOB on May 11th *appears* to be on the next statement:

byteCountforBitmaps += balloonBitmap[correctOptionColourNo][j].getByteCount();

However, I’m not sure if I can fully believe this, because surely the previous statement would have OOB’d first.  Anyway my v 1.2 code backup points to this line of code – I just don’t believe it somehow.  But whichever is the actual offending line of code, it’s still the same problem, which index is OOB and why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is here: `for (int j = 1; j <= totalNoOfDynamicImages; j++)`

Try changing it to `for (int j = 0; j < totalNoOfDynamicImages; j++)`

Comment: Ty.  I know it's probably considered bad practice, but I only use the elements 1 to 5 in the array.      totalNoOfDynamicImages is set by an sqllite call which looks up the # of rows fitting certain criteria, which, here, will return a max value of 5.   Bear in mind the app is used frequently in production, so 99.9% of the time there's no oob and it's only on this Samsung Tab A device.   I have wondered if somehow, the table it's reading totalNoOfDynamicImages  from, is somehow wrong (tho I can't see how it can be), maybe a database issue on this device.  The tables are created by the app.

Comment: totalNoOfDynamicImages = db.readDynamicObject("9", Integer.toString(21 + correctOptionColourNo - 1);   This SQL call will always return 5 (if the table is as I expect it to be).